# Propel PostgreSQL Migration unable to find adapter

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, migration, propel

I am trying to use migrations for the first time on my in-development Propel project (so I don't have to re-insert 15MB of data), but am having some difficulties.  I made the changes in my schema and ran `propel-gen diff`.  I first received an error that it couldn't locate my `buildtime-conf.xml` file.  I hadn't made one yet (since it wasn't necessary), but read that the structure should be the same as the `runtime-conf.xml`.  I copied `runtime-conf.xml` to `buildtime-conf.xml`.  And now receive the following error:

```
[propel-sql-diff] Reading databases structure...
[phingcall] Unable to find adapter for datasource [project].
Execution of target "sql-diff" failed for the following reason: /var/www/project/vendor/propel/propel1/generator/build-propel.xml:317:26: Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
    [phing] /var/www/project/vendor/propel/propel1/generator/build-propel.xml:317:26: Execution of the target buildfile failed. Aborting.
```

My runtime and buildtime files look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <propel>
        <datasources default="project">
            <datasource id="project">
                <adapter>pgsql</adapter>
                <connection>
                    <dsn>pgsql:host=###.###.###.###;dbname=database</dsn>
                    <user>USER</user>
                    <password>PASS</password>
                </connection>
            </datasource>
        </datasources>
    </propel>
</config>
```

My schema is along the lines of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="project" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <table schema="accounts" name="accounts" phpName="Account" package="accounts">
        <column />
    </table>
</database>
```

I tried changing the buildtime-conf to `<datasource id="testing">` and the error changed to `Unable to find adapter for datasource [testing]`.  So the error lies in the actual buildtime-conf file (not the schema), as far as I can tell.  I thought maybe Propel couldn't find PostgreSQL's adapter (even though it works fine in my runtime-conf), so I tried changing my adapter to `mysql`.  It came up with the same unable to find adapter error.

I'm completely lost, thoughts?

**Update:** so I was able to go into `/Propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php` and locate the line where the `Unable to find adapter` exception was thrown.  I manually defined the variable by adding the line `self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['adapter'] = 'pgsql'` and it works.  This obviously isn't verify useful for now, as I won't be able to update Propel without redoing this change.  I dumped `self::$configuration` in Propel.php and it is `NULL`, any ideas why?

Comment: What version are you running? If it is 1.6, that's still in support afaik - I'd file a bug. It seems like the migrations stuff is not initialising the connection, though I don't know the internals at all really. Also, if you want to zip up a full schema.xml and build.properties, I'll try a migration on my machine if you like (not tried them yet, but keep meaning to get around to it!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like switching a Composer dependency to `dev-master` fixes this - there is [20 commits difference](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/compare/1.7.1...master) between the current release (1.7.1) and master, at the time of writing. The migrations patch specifically [is here](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/commit/06aa3ec0345f2b0e43e6d0ebdf61697fdf1bdcaa).

Hopefully a 1.7.2 release will be made in due course, though it should be noted that the team's development effort will likely be focussed on Propel2 at present (still in alpha).

Comment: Awesome, good find and thanks for coming back to let people know @halfer. Years later and they found the simple bug, guess not many people use pgsql...

Comment: No probs @Sam, I encountered the same issue myself. I've encountered a few frustrating gotchas with migrations, but it's difficult to know how much effort to put into offering upstream fixes. It looks like there are a number of PRs waiting since at least April 2014, but the previous lead dev [was minded to merge them slowly](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/859#issuecomment-39421396), for stability reasons.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest stable version of Propel (1.7.1) it is inpossible to add the following code:

`self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['adapter'] = 'mysql';`

Resulting in the following error:

`Indirect modification of overloaded element of PropelConfiguration has no effect`

That's why, if you have only one adapter you could use:

```
/*
if (!isset(self::$configuration['datasources'][$name]['adapter'])) {
    throw new PropelException("Unable to find adapter for datasource [" . $name . "].");
}
*/
$db = DBAdapter::factory('mysql');
// register the adapter for this name
self::$adapterMap[$name] = $db;
```

This error happens only when using ./propel-gen diff. Still very strange. Hope they fix it soon.